# How to create a header which fills the background with a color throughout the width

Tags: html, css

I've set the background-color for **body** section to gray and created an **id** for the header section, setting it to backgroud-color white. However, I need the white color to be filled throughout the width. How do I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<body>

 <div id="header">
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div>

 <div>
  <h2>About Us</h2>
 </div>

  </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
}

#header {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height: 70px;
}
```

This is how it's suppose to look, http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/
I mean, how the black color of the header is set throughtout the page width.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you get with your actual code ?

Comment: @Gwendal: http://s2.postimg.org/9gzdiz761/cards.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are after some of these methods:

### Method 1

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#F8F8F8;
}

#header {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="header">
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h2>About Us</h2>
 </div>
</body>
```

### Mehtod 2

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#F8F8F8;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="header">
   <div class="wrapper"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <h2>About Us</h2>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the css on the linked page,

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: It works but the text inside the h2 tag won't appear after I use it

Answer (score 0):

You have white margins because of the browser's default css rules. You'll find what you need here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a style to the body that will reset the default browser margin/padding being applied.

```
body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}
```

I recommend looking into reset/normalize/reboot css files. Bootstrap comes with a really good boilerplate file that you should consider replicating for future projects.

Hope this helps